# Designing symmetrically in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to draw something like that black dragon, but the wing is the most difficult part.
I draw some shape, copy-rotate it, then apply Pathfinder minus front.
Is my approach okay? I don't want to lose the symmetry, which is why I didn't use the pen tool and manually draw it.

Does this have to be done with pen tool? I really do not understand how to draw the wing and cut out all those white designs off the black background. :'( 
[image]

Comment: It will make you life so much easier, If you duplicate the "black spots" and manually adjust them along the moon shaped circle. If you look at the original illustration, you will see that even the artist redraw each "wing" separately.

Comment: Thank you. but i feel weird. this question got 3 closing votes on 'clarify' ground.... isnt my question clear enough? Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: The question is clear, maybe a bit complicated for people who have no idea about illustrator or can't read a texts till the end. However, it is understandable, that you want to do it symmetrical, that is why you made the "black spots" along a path, which I think is along the red moon shaped circle and that is why you are trying to avoid to redraw it with the pen tool.

Comment: yes.... :( :'( Thank you so much. at least you made effort to help me... i thought nobody cares :'(

Comment: In order to get this as good as the original, you'll have to draw it manually, just like the artist did. [Von Glitschka](https://www.glitschkastudios.com/) is an artist who uses (probably invented) this style and makes gazillions of tutorials about it. I learned my Illustrator skills from him.

Comment: Thank you.... i have been watching  his 'vector drawing graphics'  and yes he is BOSS, he is so cool...!!  Dean McClelland's one on one- illustrator fundamental is also in my list. but sometimes i cant get things done the way they do...  only then i come here. :)

Comment: and sometimes i feel to keep pace with VON  one must have some profound knowledge in illustrator.... sometimes i dont get him...because am  less knowledgeable... because i dnt know  each and every tool, their application... i need to learn a lot... :(

Comment: I can see that starting with a pattern brush applied to a curve and some adjustments after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to find the middle point of the circle, before you cut it to a moon shape, then mark it. After that place the first "black spot" to the place where you want to have the first negative space of the wing. Then select that "black spot", press "alt" + "r" on the center of the marked spot. A window will pop up and you can choose the angle that for the next "black spot". IMPORTANT, press "copy". when you are happy with the placement, then press "ctrl" + "d" to duplicate the action of the rotation. Try it as long out until you have the result that you like.

See the image to understand what I mean with marking the middle point of the circle.

[image]

If you have questions, please let me know.

Comment: wow. it helps. i just understand my mistake after following your answer. 

i made mistake by cutting the ellipse before rotating the negative-space-creator shape. as it was half i set the rotate anchor point  on guess.... that is why it didn't produce the result like the main picture.... 

but now as you instructed i did it. and it gives my design much more aesthetic look...

saying THANK YOU - wont be enough to express how much happy i am right now.

i am waiting for AN ANSWER since i hv posted it.

its 3 AM here.
now i can sleep.

<3 <3 <3  THANK YOU SO  SO SO MUCH :)